# Ячейка как ссылка (всплывающее окно на jQuery)?

Tags: jquery

Доброго дня, люди добрые, подскажите как вызвать всплывающее окно при клике на всю область ячейки?

```
<a href="#popup1" name="loadpopunder">Ссылка</a>
```

При клике на "Ссылка" всплывающее окно нормально открывается

но как задействовать всё поле ячейки в таблице - как ссылку?

Пробовал таким образом, при нажатии на ячейку ничего не происходит.

```
<td class="td1" onClick="document.location='#popup1'" name="loadpopunder"></td>
```

Используется следующий скрипт всплывающего окна

```
//Pop-under window II- By JavaScript Kit 
//Credit notice must stay intact for use 
//Visit http://javascriptkit.com for this script
//Pop-under only once per browser session? (0=no, 1=yes) 
//Specifying 0 will cause popunder to load every time page is loaded var once_per_session=1
///No editing beyond here required/////

function get_cookie(Name) {
    var search = Name + "="
    var returnvalue = "";
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search) if (offset != -1) {
            // if cookie exists 
            offset += search.length
            // set index of beginning of value 
            end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
            // set index of end of cookie value 
            if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
            returnvalue = unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
        }
    }
    return returnvalue;
}

function loadornot() {
    if (get_cookie('popunder') == '') {
        loadpopunder() document.cookie = "popunder=yes"
    }
}

function loadpopunder() {
    var id = '#popup1';

    //Get the screen height and width 
    var mask1Height = jQuery(document).height();
    var mask1Width = jQuery(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen 
    jQuery('#mask1').css({
        'width': mask1Width,
        'height': mask1Height
    });

    //transition effect
    jQuery('#mask1').fadeIn(1000);
    jQuery('#mask1').fadeTo("slow", 0.8);

    //Get the window height and width 
    var winH = jQuery(window).height();
    var winW = jQuery(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center 
    jQuery(id).css('top', winH / 2 - jQuery(id).height() / 2);
    jQuery(id).css('left', winW / 2 - jQuery(id).width() / 2);

    //transition effect 
    jQuery(id).fadeIn(2000);
}
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('a[name=loadpopunder]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        loadpopunder(id);
        // вызываем по клику 
    });
    jQuery('.window1 .close1').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#mask1, .window1').hide();
    });
    jQuery('#mask1').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).hide();
        jQuery('.window1').hide();
    });
});
```

Заранее очень благодарен!

Comment: @Алекс-ми, на будущее - форматировать код надо выделением его и нажатием на кнопку **{}**

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
jQuery('a[name=loadpopunder]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        loadpopunder(id);
        // вызываем по клику 
    });
```

на

```
jQuery('.loadpopunder').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = jQuery(this).data('target');
        loadpopunder(id);
        // вызываем по клику 
    });
```

и

```
<td class="td1" onClick="document.location='#popup1'" name="loadpopunder"></td>
```

на

```
<td class="td1 loadpopunder"  data-target="#popup1"></td>
```

Comment: Действительно, загружается,
только при клике <a class="close1" href="#">Закрыть</a>
Начинается загрузка всплывающего окна снова.

При обычном вызове <a href="#popup1" name="loadpopunder">Ссылка</a>
такого не происходит.

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: я вас не понял. вы следовали моим рекомендациям ?

Comment: Да конечно, бесконечная загрузка происходит после применения ваших рекоммендаций!

Comment: Контент всплывающего окна

<div id="boxes1">
<div style="display: none; position: fixed;" id="popup1" class="window1">
Контент
<a href="#" class="close1">Закрыть</a></div>
<div style="display: none; position: fixed;" id="mask1"></div>

Comment: у вас там id захордкожен, вот работающий пример http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/zBAWh/ 

вообще все не так делается если, что и я бы этот код на вашем месте выкинул пока не поздно.

Comment: как-то очень странно, http://jsfiddle.net/zBAWh/5/ тут всё работает верно, а на сайте бесконечная загрузка при нажатии <a class="close1" href="#">Закрыть</a> либо на пустое поле

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/zBAWh/9/ вот чуть получший код, насчет того что у вас на сайте происходит я не уверен. т.к. вы очень много делаете  очень неправильно.